# python import function doesn't import the program

Tags: python, flask

I have a python flask program(mini project) which get the image form user and process OCR detection. It works perfectly but now I came to notice that this code executes once when the server started and if the user selects the image again after running for the first time, it does not work properly. I simply used `print`  statement to detect where the error has been occurred and came to know that the import function not working at the second and more iterations.

my main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import shutil
import logging
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])
from livereload import Server, shell

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
    
@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the files part
        if 'files[]' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
        for file in files:
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                log_file(filename)
                                
        flash('File(s) successfully uploaded')
        ocr_detection()
        return redirect('/')
                
        

def ocr_detection():#OCR
        print('OCR')
        import ocrDetection
        ocrDetection.mask()
        flash('JSON created')


def log_file(filename):
        log_format = '%(asctime)s %(message)s'
        log_path="D:/SARIGHA/OCR/source_code/log_path/"+"check_log.log"
        logging.basicConfig(filename=log_path ,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',level=logging.INFO,datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
        logging.info("FILE UPLOADED_"+filename)
                              
if __name__ == "__main__":
        #app.jinja_env.auto_reload = True
        app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD']=True
        app.run(host='192.168.106.51',debug=True,use_reloader=True)
```

It seems that the control enters into `ocr_detection()` and execute the  `print('OCR')` and `flash('JSON created')` but not importing ocrDetection `import ocrDetection` and work

I also tried by putting `import ocrDetection` at the top of the program like:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import shutil
import logging
import ocrDetection
```

this makes me in big trouble that the detection starts before the flask server open.

Comment: It looks like `ocrDetection` is more of a script than a library. `import` will run the file once then cache the result for later access, so if `ocrDetection` does work when it gets run it's not going to work. Running it as a script using `subprocess.run` would be the right way to do this then, though I have no idea how it gets its input. Alternatively, if you control `ocrDetection` you could fix it to work as a library which would, say, take a file object as input and return the OCR'd data (as python structures).

Comment: @Masklinn I already mentioned that is the python flask , import function does work only when I closed my terminal every time. As ocrDetection is a python script that is imported in main.py only once, but subprocess.run method starts every time in my program now where the control reads script line one by one, anyhow now my code words perfectly what I want

Comment: flask and import work just fine, you're just not understanding *how* they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you will go with the subprocess method in python:

```
def ocr_detection():
        try:
                proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("python ocrDetection.py"),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                out = proc.communicate()
      
        except Exception as e:
                print('something went wrong')
                print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reloading the module helps?

```py
from importlib import reload
try:
  ocrDetection = reload(ocrDetection)
except NameError:
  import ocrDetection
```

Comment: no reload() not makes a different still having the same problem